# jQuery accordian — click to expand, click to close

Tags: jquery, accordion, slide

I'm having a little trouble with some script I have written. HTML and jQuery is shown below. Currently if you click an .each-question title, it's answer slides down. If you click another .each-question title, the answer that was open slides up and the new answer slides down. However, if you click the .each-question title of the same answer that's already open, it fails to slideUp and rather slides up and slides back down.

I want it so if you click the title of the answer already open, it slides up and stays up.

```
$('.faq > .each-question').click(function() {
    $('.faq > .each-answer').slideUp('normal'); 
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
});
$('.faq > .each-answer').hide();

<div class="each-question"> Where do your ideas come from? </div>
<div class="each-answer"> Text for answer </div>
```

UPDATE — jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YZBLg/

Cheers in advance,
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mido_rizk007/YZBLg/1/):

```
$('.faq > .each-question').click(function() {
    $('.faq > .each-answer').slideUp( 'slow'); 
    if($(this).next('.each-answer').is(':not(:visible)')){
        $(this).next('.each-answer').slideToggle('normal');
    }
});
$('.faq > .each-answer').hide();
```

Comment: This works same as before. But if you click the title of the answer that is already open, it doesn't close... it just slides back open again.

Comment: @rdck i really do it as you say but i put the code above and i forget update jsfiddle so can you see at : http://jsfiddle.net/mido_rizk007/YZBLg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.slideToggle()`

```
$('.faq > .each-answer').slideToggle('normal'); 
$(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I felt this would've worked but it creates a few more errors i.e clicking on the title slideToggles the wrong answer etc.

Comment: create a fiddle if possible.